# Sybase token datastream length was not correct

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement, sybase

Getting below error while saving a binary into a image column.

org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into lens_dal_data(dal_cd,user_id,insert_dt,exp_dt,url,map_data,cat_cd) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL state [ZZZZZ]; error code [3805]; The token datastream length was not correct. This is an internal protocol error.
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: The token datastream length was not correct. This is an internal protocol error.

Answer (score 3):

Was able to figure out after fighting 2 days on this.

It's a issue with jconn4 jar and version 7.0.0

when we upgraded the jar to 7.0.7 the issue is resolved.

Comment: You Should accept this as the answer. I hit the same issue, upon jconn4 upgrade its fixed