# Not able to insert large string in Sybase DB

Tags: java, sybase, jdbctemplate

I am trying to store large(more than 20000 characters) html string in the Sybase DB in TEXT datatype but getting two problems.

1. When I try to insert manually, only 8192 characters are inserted.
2. When I try through jdbctemplate, I get error as "error code [3805] ; The token datastream length was not correct. This is an internal protocol error". 
   Though it works for small strings from jdbctemplate.

Please help.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504099/sybase-token-datastream-length-was-not-correct

Comment: @SudhirOjha can you give me live links to download jconnect latest jar or procedure to download it?

Comment: @SudhirOjha I have upgraded jconnect jar and my second problem is solved. Now I do not get the error which I specified and data is also inserted. But the first problem is as it is. I am not able to store more than 8192 characters in the database in TEXT datatype. can you help.

Comment: Use datatype as `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the function `set textsize number`. 
Maximum is 16382 (or so) which is also the max of a VARCHAR.

Comment: The max isn't based upon a varchar limit - see http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X11184.htm
Some SQL tools may have a limit but isql for example you can select the full size of the blob the example on that URL sets it to 2GB.

Answer (score 0):

The second issue which I have listed got resolved when I upgraded the jconnect jar (upgraded to 16.0). (Following Sudhir's comment)

The first issue which I listed was not actually truncation issue, rather it was something related to the rapid sql on which I run my queries. I found that when I run select query on rapid sql it gives me max 8k characters(truncated string) . It might be because of certain settings in the rapid sql. 
But the main issue is resolved and I can retrieve whole string using jdbc now.